# problems with Join query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I've got data in two tables my first table contains

- first name
- last name

my second table contain

- userid
- first name
- last name

I'm trying to write a sql query to get the userid of a particular user but I'm getting empty set while executing the query. Could anyone please verify that the query I'm using is right? It seems ok to me

```
 select users.id 
 FROM TABLE1 AS r 
   LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS users 
     ON (users.firstname = r.firstname 
     AND users.lastname=r.lastname)
```

Comment: Are you sure that firstname and lastname are exactly the same in both tables?  Capitalization, trailing (and leading) spaces, all of these things are hidden gotchas.

Comment: Aren't you using the same table TABLE2.

Comment: Is the second table containing two columns or three? The definition implies two while the query implies three.

Comment: You should never join tables on a free-text field - it will lead to endless problems - especially when someone decides you need to support chinese and now your collations all need to change. Use Ids.

Answer (score 2):

You use twice the same table (TABLE2), but in the description you state that you have two tables.

Comment: sorry I'm mistaken, actually I meant select users.id 
  FROM TABLE1 AS r 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS users 
    ON (users.firstname = r.firstname AND users.lastname=r.lastname)

Comment: as proposed by Brian Hoover, you may try to trim the fields you are using in your join condition.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think you want this:

```
 select users.id 
      FROM TABLE1 AS r 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS users 
        ON (users.firstname = r.firstname AND users.lastname=r.lastname)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select users.id 
      FROM TABLE1 AS r 
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS users 
        ON (lower(ltrim(rtrim(users.firstname))) = lower(ltrim(rtrim(r.firstname))) AND lower(ltrim(rtrim(users.lastname)))=lower(ltrim(rtrim(r.lastname))))
```

Comment: do you have single column for firstname and lastname in second table?